# How to call a method as a custom callback in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I need to run the following method after every 5K iterations.

```
def evaluation_matrix(path_true,path_pred):
    print(path_true,"\n",path_pred)

    true_list_new, pred_list_new = read_from_folder(path_true = path_true , path_pred = path_pred)

    try:
        scikit_metrix(true_list_new = true_list_new,pred_list_new = pred_list_new)
    except:
        print("An exception occurred")
```

I'm hoping to use it as a callback in model.fit_generator function. How to achive this? That is parameter passing + 5K interval?

```
history = model.fit_generator(generator = myGene, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=epoch, verbose = 1, callbacks=[],shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom callback is a powerful tool to customize the behavior of a Keras model during training, evaluation, or inference.

Below is an example where we are calculating gradient after every epochs. Similarly you can do more customize with many inbuilt methods. You can find more about it here - https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback

**Note:** I was using tensorflow 1.15.0

```
# (1) Importing dependency
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1000)

# (2) Get Data
import tflearn.datasets.oxflower17 as oxflower17
x, y = oxflower17.load_data(one_hot=True)

# (3) Create a sequential model
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(224,224,3), kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation before passing it to the next layer
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Passing it to a dense layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(224*224*3,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 2nd Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 3rd Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(17))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

# (4) Compile 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
epoch_gradient = []

# Define the Required Callback Function
class GradientCalcCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def get_gradient_func(model):
      grads = K.gradients(model.total_loss, model.trainable_weights)
      inputs = model.model._feed_inputs + model.model._feed_targets + model.model._feed_sample_weights
      func = K.function(inputs, grads)
      return func
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
      get_gradient = get_gradient_func(model)
      grads = get_gradient([x, y, np.ones(len(y))])
      epoch_gradient.append(grads)

model.fit(x, y, batch_size=64, epochs= 4, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[GradientCalcCallback()])

# (7) Convert to a 2 dimensiaonal array of (epoch, gradients) type
gradient = np.asarray(epoch_gradient)
print("Total number of epochs run:", epoch)
print("Gradient Array has the shape:",gradient.shape)
```

Comment: in class GradientCalcCallback there are two methods get_gradient_func(model) & on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None). get_gradient_func() called by on_epoch_end() function. From where on_epoch_end() is called? how model is visible to class GradientCalcCallback in get_gradient = get_gradient_func(model) ?

Comment: on_epoch_end() is called by itself on end of every epoch because of callbacks=[GradientCalcCallback()]. You can find many such inbuilt methods to use. You can find more about it in the link i posted - https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback.

Comment: if on_epoch_end() is called after every epoch how to make that interval for 5000 epochs?

Comment: Simple, keep a counter called epoch_count to count the epochs using on_epoch_end or on_epoch_begin and on epoch_count counter reaches 5000, call your custom function. :)

Comment: @harinsamaranayake - If I have answered your question, can you please accept and upvote it. Thank You.